# Modify Add Method in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I'm new to entity framework technology and I just generated 3 classes from my tables:

- Project
- Resource
- Employees

I wanted to set a condition that the resource can't be used by two projects and I want that in my project's Add method how can I modify it, is it even possible to  modify it?

```
public partial class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Resource { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Manager { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Deadline { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Emploee Emploee { get; set; }
    public virtual Resource Resource1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using code first, model first or data first?

Comment: That seems to be a business logic. Handle it in your business layer before you even call the `Add` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify it but it will override when you generate again. Add partial class and put your method there.

```
//Your partial class
public partial class Project
{

   public string DoCustomWork()
   {
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using data first, if you want the resource to be unique to a single project, then create a unique constraint on the resource FK in the project table.

Comment: That's not going to work because i want to use that resource again when the project is done.